# Parameterization of the set of oriented rectangles

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, rectangles

I am interested in the set of oriented rectangles, that are centered on the origin, and can be described by their width, height and angle.

I am looking for a "good" parameterization that is non-ambiguous (a rectangle should correspond to only one set of parameters) and continuous (close rectangles should have close parameters).

For example, if I parameterize rectangles with a positive width and height and a 2D rotation in $[0, 2\pi)$, the parameterization is ambiguous as adding $\pi$ to the angle produced the same rectangle. If I restrict the angle to $[0, \pi)$, the parameterization is still ambiguous as adding $\pi/2$ to the angle and switching the width and the height produce the same rectangle. If I restrict the angle to $[0, \pi/2]$, the parameterization becomes unambiguous, but it is not continuous anymore, as the parameterization switches height and width when the angle crosses the 0/$\pi/2$ boundary.

At first I thought I could fall back to the parameterization of ellipses, but there is a major difference between rectangles and ellipses: when an ellipse collapse into a circle, its only parameter is its size. When a rectangle collapses into a square, it still has a rotation component. And the parameterization of this rotation should respect the order of rotational symmetry of 4 of the square, which is not shared with general rectangles which have an order of 2.

To be more rigorous, what I want is a homeomorphism between the space of rectangles and a manifold embedded in some $R^n$ (thanks @joriki). I think I also want at some point the manifold to be describable by a set of equations to be usable in practice, like $\|p\|^2=1$ for $U(1)$, but let's put that aside for now.

My question is then, what is a parameterization of rotated rectangles with these properties? Is it possible to find one, or on the opposite, can we prove that no such parameterization exists?

I am absolutely not knowledgeable in this matter and probably put inappropriate tags to this question, apologies in advance.

EDIT: I *think* this question might have to do with Lie groups and representation theory, and whether or not this group accepts a faithful representation (which I fear it doesn't).

Comment: Consider stipulating that $w \leq h$.

Comment: @OrangeMushroom Then your representation is not continous, as very close rectangles will have differences in angle of $\pi/2$.

Comment: I was just noting that you didn't mention this condition, and might want this in order to make the map injective, or nonambiguous. Also, you seem to be using continuous in a non-standard way. What you seem to mean is that the inverse map from the space of rectangles is continuous.

Comment: This is an interesting question. (I never understand why some questions that serious thought has gone into don't get upvotes.) But I think you need to be a bit more precise. Apparently you wouldn't mind the angle wrapping around from $2\pi$ to $0$, even though this is also a discontinuity in the mapping from the rectangle space to the parameter space. Presumably you don't mind this because you consider an angle parameter as an element of $U(1)$ (or a point on the unit circle), where this discontinuity doesn't exist. ...

Comment: ... But then you could treat the entire parameter space that way and make identifications that remove the discontinutities. So perhaps what you want is a parametrization in terms of numbers and/or elements of $U(1)$, without more complicated identifications in the parameter space?

Comment: @joriki You're absolutely right. I assumed that I could parameterize 2D rotations in a continuous way, typically using a point on the unit circle as you said. However, I am unable to find a good parameterization for oriented rectangles that way. Now that I think of it, maybe a good embedding in a larger space would work if there is a simple enough constrain to describe the manifold (like for $U(1)$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150641/discussion-between-joriki-and-user209974).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this yields an embedding of the $3$-dimensional manifold of rectangles in $\mathbb R^5$ that fulfils your criteria:

Denote the polar coordinates of two midpoints by $(a,\phi)$ and $(b,\psi)$, with $\psi\equiv\phi+\frac\pi2\pmod{2\pi}$. A rectangle is represented by

$$\left(s,\epsilon\cos2\phi,\epsilon\sin2\phi,\cos4\phi,\sin4\phi\right)\;,$$

where $s=\log\sqrt{ab}$ is the scale of the rectangle and $\epsilon=\log\sqrt\frac ab$ is its eccentricity. Adding $\pi$ to $\phi$ leaves this representation invariant. Adding $\frac\pi2$ to $\phi$ and swapping $a$ and $b$ also leaves it invariant: It adds $2\pi$ to $4\phi$ and $\pi$ to $2\phi$, and the resulting sign change in the second and third coordinates is cancelled by the sign change in $\epsilon$.

$a$, $b$ and $\phi$ can be reconstructed from $(s,x,y,u,v)$ as follows: $\epsilon=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $a=\mathrm e^{s+\epsilon}$, $b=\mathrm e^{s-\epsilon}$. If $\epsilon\ne0$, $\phi$ is defined up to multiples of $\pi$ and given by $\frac12\operatorname{atan2}(y,x)$, whereas if $\epsilon=0$, $\phi$ is defined up to multiples of $\frac\pi2$ and given by $\frac14\operatorname{atan2}(v,u)$, where $\operatorname{atan2}$ is the [two-argument arctangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

The last two coordinates seem a bit wasteful, but I’m not sure whether this can be avoided, since, as you noted, we need to prevent the representation from shrinking to a point at $\epsilon=0$ and instead identify $\phi$ and $\phi+\frac\pi2$ when $\epsilon=0$, and I’m not sure whether this is topologically possible with a single extra coordinate.

If we go back to your original formulation where you essentially allowed elements of $U(1)$ as parameters, the two pairs of real coordinates can be combined into complex numbers, so we have a real number $s$, a complex number $\epsilon\mathrm e^{2\mathrm i\phi}$ and a phase $\mathrm e^{4\mathrm i\phi}$.

Comment: Helpful but foremost absolutely insightful. Love it.